# MergesSort and Where are the assignments actually counted?

Tags: java, big-o, variable-assignment, mergesort

So let us say we have an ascending array of size ten that goes from 1->10. 
I understand the splitting of the array, but what I don't seem to understand is when an assignment happens. Here is my current interpretation of what it means:

```
  (1) 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
  (2) 1,2,3,4,5     6,7,8,9,10
  (3) 1,2  3,4  5     6,7   8,9  10
  (4) 1  2  |  3  4  |  5     |  6   7 | 8   9  | 10
  (5) 1,2    3,4       5         6,7      8,9     10
  //(5.5) 1,2,3,4   5          6,7,8,9    10
  (6)  1,2,3,4,5        6,7,8,9,10
  (7)  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

I'm unsure if we go from step 5 to 6 or if we do step 5.5. Other than that, I assume that Step 5 has 10 assignments, Step 6 has 10 more assignments, and Step 7 has 10 more for a total of 30 assignments. I am confident that this has to be wrong, since I am unsure if Step (2),(3),(4) are counted as well or if I am even counting the assignments to begin with. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: To count variable assignments, we'd have to know how this particular mergesort implementation uses variables. Even if we are to only count assignments to array elements, the implementation matters (for instance, an implementation might try to reuse arrays, or use a new array in each step, which would obviously affect the number of assignments).

Comment: It even depends on the input, 0 assignments in this case because 1 to 10 is already sorted.

Comment: but doesn't merging the array count as assigning? Let's just say it is a generic recursive mergesort.

Comment: If counting assignments I would assume in place sorting and count swapping values as 3 assignments. So worst case something like 30 * 3,3 = 100 assignments. But take  8 or 16 items to see the pattern. It's easier because you end up with equal sizes at each merge.

Comment: The term "assignment" is only well defined for a single variable or array element. Sure, any mergesort implementation will assign variables, but how many assignments it needs depends on how it is implemented. Knowing that it is "generic" and "recursive" is not sufficient to count assignments.

Comment: You need permutation of the input. You can count the number of swaps regardless of the implementation.

Comment: Merging is just swapping items.

Answer (score 0):

You should count comparisons. The nummer of comparisons is O(N log N)

Comment: How do you know that OP should count comparisons rather than assignments?

Comment: Because OP tagged big o and is uncertain about what to count.